# Autofac Error for params Argument

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a type `Model` that has a constructor:

`Model(string name, IFoo dependency)`

I want to use a factory to create instances of `Model` off of the `container` using a different value for name each time. To do this I register my `Model` type and then the factory like so:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Model>();`
var container = builder.Build();
var factory = builder.Resolve<Func<string, Model>>();
```

The problem comes in later where I have class `Consumer` that has the following constructor:

`public Consumer(IFoo depedency, params Model[] optionalInputs)`

When I go to resolve `Consumer` I get an exception because in order to get my factory I had to register `Model` even though I don't ever want to resolve it except through the factory. I don't want to use a `NamedParameter` or anything like that because there is no default instance to use, I just want any optional collections such as `params Model[] ...` to be set to an empty array when they are encountered.
`

Answer (score 2):

You could change the registration of `Consumer` to specify how the instance shall be constructed:

```
builder.Register(c => new Consumer(c.Resolve<IFoo>()));
```

This way the `params` parameter will be ignored.

> I just want any optional collections such as params Model[] ... to be set to an empty array when they are encountered.

From my point of view this sounds like a flaw in your design. You want Autofac to create your `Consumer` instance but you don't want it to set the `optionalInputs` parameter. In that case, why don't you simply remove the parameter altogether?

#### Update

Following your comment, I guess you could add an explicit registration for the `Model[]` type:

```
builder.RegisterInstance<Model[]>(Array.Empty<Model>());
```

I've tried this approach and it seems to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I would like to try to explain again as I think you don't quite understand the question. I could certainly use the lambda form of registration as you suggest but it isn't as maintainable as the factory and I am really interested if it can be done with a factory. What I want is to tell Autofac, hey whenever you see a `Model` you should have no idea how to resolve that and if you see an optional `Model` parameter just leave it be but please keep this factory method for me that will serve as my only means of creating `Model` objects from the container.

Comment: Maybe what I mentioned in my last comment is or isn't possible, and that is what I am looking for. To me what I am asking for seems like a feature that Autofac should provide and it seems like a limitation that it doesn't (meaning that if I was to supply a code update to the Autofac source code to support this scenario I would imagine they would accept it since it seems like a normal user scenario rather than something that is problematic or not possible).

Comment: I've updated my answer. I guess it should work, but I'm still not sure if it is the best approach.